# Auto cancellation of subscription in Zuora

Tags: zuora, zuora-soap

I would like to auto cancel subscriptions if the due invoice does not paid for certain days and **Cancellation Effective Dates** should be set as invoice due date, so that no refund and due invoice will be pending in the customer account.

Reference:

1. https://knowledgecenter.zuora.com/BC_Subscription_Management/Subscriptions/H_Cancellations
2. https://knowledgecenter.zuora.com/BC_Subscription_Management/Subscriptions/Handling_Cancellations_in_a_Subscription_Business

In every documentation, I can see that how to cancelled it manually or through API, I would like to know is there any configuration in Zuora available for auto cancellation.

Answer (score 0):

There is no auto-cancellation in zuora, you have to enable the invoice due callout and integrate an API which will get the request and will perform the cancellation of subscription.